# How check if an array key exist in another array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I have two array, the first one looks like this (take note that `created` and `approved` are only two from about six element for this example);

```
Array
(
    [created] => Array
        (
            [label] => Order created
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ROLE_USER
                )

            [next_states] => Array
                (
                    [approve] => Array
                        (
                            [target] => approved
                        )

                )

        )

    [approved] => Array
        (
            [label] => Order approved
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ROLE_USER
                )

            [next_states] => Array
                (
                    [order] => Array
                        (
                            [target] => ordered
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

As soon as a step (like `created` etc.) is completed, another array is populated like this; (Lets call this array `arrayFinished`)

```
Array
(
    [created] => 1
)
```

How can I compare these two arrays to get three different states; `completed`, `active`, and `disabled`. Something like; if step `created` is in `arrayfinished` echo complete, elseif step `created` is the last one added to `arrayfinished` echo active, else disabled.

This is what I tried but I get a wrong output;

```
foreach ($steps as $key => $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $arrayFinished)) {
                echo $value['label'] . ' is complete<br>';
            } elseif ($key === end($arrayFinished)) {
                echo $value['label'] . ' is active<br>';
            } else {
                echo $value['label'] . ' is disabled<br>';
            }
        }
```

This is may output from above `foreach`:

```
Order created is complete
Order approved is disabled
Order ordered is disabled
Order delivered is disabled
Invoice verified correct is disabled
Invoice paid is disabled
```

The first one (created) should be active because it is the 'last' one in the array.

Can somebody please help me out getting this because I struggle now a few hours with something that sounds simple. Will twig be easier? Because I need to set a div class to the value returned.

If done in PHP how to I get it to Twig?

Please, I need help desperately.

Comment: `end` will give you the last `value` in the array not the key.  You can do `end( array_keys( $arrayFinished ) )`, however you would be better off storing the last key in a variable before the loop, that would help performance a smidge.

Comment: @RyanVincent I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

`end()` will just move to the last item of array, then you need to use `key()` function:

```
foreach ($steps as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $arrayFinished)) {
        echo $value['label'] . ' is complete<br>';
    } else {
        end($arrayFinished);
        if ($key === key($arrayFinished)) {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is active<br>';
        } else {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is disabled<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer give the same output as the answer above. The last one remain 'complete' as well and doesn't change to 'active'

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments,

```
    $keys = array_keys($arrayFinished);
    $last = end($keys);

    foreach ($steps as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $arrayFinished)) {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is complete<br>';
        } elseif ($key === $last) {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is active<br>';
        } else {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is disabled<br>';
        }
    }
```

Get the last key of that array outside the loop, instead of using `end()` and instead of repeating that stuff unnecessarily during the loop.  And may avoid some useless errors.  Also by using `array_keys` and then `end` you are not moving the pointer in the original array to the end.  That said, typically that wouldn't cause to much issues anyway, but....

You could also change this

```
    ....
     if (array_key_exists($key, $arrayFinished)) {
    ....
```

To

```
    ....
     if (isset($arrayFinished[$key])) {
    ....
```

Which I think is a tiny bit faster, too.  But, it has the same effect.

UPDATE: change this

```
       if (array_key_exists($key, $arrayFinished)) {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is complete<br>';
        } elseif ($key === $last) {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is active<br>';
        } else {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is disabled<br>';
        }
```

To

```
       if ($key === $last) {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is active<br>';
        } elseif (array_key_exists($key, $arrayFinished)) {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is complete<br>';
        } else {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is disabled<br>';
        }
```

The reason is that the second condition will never be evaluated because if it is true then the first one is true as well, essentially if the key is the last one in the array, then it is also set.  So, the second one will never be evaluated...

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I still don't get the last one to be 'active' it still shows 'complete'

Comment: without know what the contents of `$steps` and `$arrayFinished` is it's impossible to tell.  you list some arrays but it's hard to tell by the question which is which.

Comment: Sorry the small, short one is $arrayFinished. And the bigger one is $steps

Comment: what is the `the last one to be 'active' `

Comment: should be checking `isset($arrayFinished['approved'])` to get `is complete` for the output if I understand everything.  If that is the case then it must be set in `$arrayFinished` you'll have to output those things and see what they actually are to know if its a problem with the logic or the data.

Comment: the last one in `$arrayFinished`. I know in the example in my question only one shows. Won't that be the last one in the array as well?

Comment: When more steps is completed that array (`$arrayFinished`) gets filled up with other steps. Then it will look like this; Array
(
    [created] => 1,
    [approved] => 1
)

Comment: then it's correct to say it `is complete` because the array key `approved` is set in the `$arrayFinished` variable.  Make sense.   You're asking it `is the key approved set in $arrayFinished` if so say `is complete`.  In the first condition check

Comment: Ok but what if a next steps gets added like this; Array
(
    [created] => 1,
    [approved] => 1,
    [ordered] => 1,
    [delivered] => 1,
)

Comment: `approved` is still set is it not?  The first condition will still be true in other words and it will/should say `is complete`, if that is not what you want you will have to change the logic or the data to get the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I think my question is not clear enough

Comment: Ok, good luck time for me to head to work.  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: To be clear though, if I have everything right, it works correctly it just doesn't give you what you want.  You may want to switch the first condition, with the second one.  once the first one passes the second part of the `elseif` is never evaluated.

Comment: Ok, I'll recheck everything

Comment: You should check for the end first... because if its the end it's always set.  @Mentos93 - one last update to the answer before I go.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($steps as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $arrayFinished)) {
            if (count($arrayFinished) > 1) {
                echo $value['label'] . ' is active<br>';
            } else {
                 echo $value['label'] . ' is complete<br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo $value['label'] . ' is disabled<br>';
        }
    }
```